# order by WHERE LIKE returned result

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with the following columns:

```
id | ip | url
```

where id is the primary key.

I would like to return the counts of the ips based on a `WHERE LIKE` of the country code. for example, all the urls have the same structure in them: `www.someWebsite.com/countryCode/blabla`. A few entries to demonstrate:

```
id | ip | url

1 | 255.255.255.255 | www.someWebsite.com/US/blabla
2 | 127.0.0.1 | www.someWebsite.com/UK/blabla
3 | 111.111.222.245 | www.someWebsite.com/FR/blabla
4 | 111.111.222.245 | www.someWebsite.com/NL/blabla
...
```

But the thing i have tons of countries and case distinction is too much. Is there a way to do it without using cases? I was going for something along the lines of:

```
select ip, COUNT(ip) AS MOST_FREQUENT
from myTable
WHERE url LIKE 'www.someWebsite.com/UK/%'
GROUP BY ip
ORDER BY COUNT(url) DESC
```

but that returns each ip and the urls associated with them while i'm aiming for the count of ips from each country.

Comment: All the country code with be two character long ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the country code is going to be only two character long (general standard), then you can utilize some string operations like `Substring_Index()` and `Left()`:

```
select LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'www.someWebsite.com/', -1), 2) AS country_code, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS ip_count 
from myTable
WHERE url LIKE 'www.someWebsite.com/%'
GROUP BY country_code
ORDER BY ip_count DESC
```

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, ''www.someWebsite.com/', -1)` for `url = 'www.someWebsite.com/US/blabla'` will return `'US/blabla'`.

Now, `LEFT('US/blabla', 2)` will return the first two characters from the left which is the country code: `US`. You can then `GROUP BY` on this country code and count distinct (unique) ip values.

Comment: @ILovePHP sorry. there was a small change needed. Check the updated answer please. I changed `1` in the substring_index to `-1`